# Updating multiple items within same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to make a stock take application, My view loads all my stock with one editor.
My controller is not getting any of the data from the view?

I want to be able to edit all my stock at the same time? 
How can I do this

Model Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FlatSystem.Models
{
public class Stock
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Item_Name { get; set; }
    public int Actual_Stock { get; set; }
    public int Wanted_Stock { get; set; }


}
}
```

View Code

```
@model IEnumerable<FlatSystem.Models.Stock>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="sidemenu">
<div class="sidemenu-heading">
    ReStock
</div>
<div class="div-body">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Item Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Wanted Stock
    </th>
    <th>
        Stock On Hand
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item_Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Wanted_Stock)
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Actual_Stock)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Actual_Stock)
    </div>
    </td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </tr>
    }
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Controller Code

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReStock(List<Stock> stock)
    {
        foreach (var item in stock)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                GR.InsertOrUpdate(item);
            }
        }
        GR.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Restock");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without model class, but idea is that your edit `inputs` must contain index in `name attribute`.

Something like this:

```
@for(int i = 0: i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Item_Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Wanted_Stock)
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].Actual_Stock)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model[i].Actual_Stock)
    </div>
    </td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].ID)
    </tr>
}
```

**Added:**

Sorry, thanks to **Darin Dimitrov**, you can't access `IEnumerable` by index, use `List` or `Array`.

Comment: His model is of type `IEnumerable<FlatSystem.Models.Stock>`, you cannot access it by index. You should update your answer by taking into account that in order for your solution to work he needs to change his model type.

Comment: No, **it can't be** `foreach`. Please read the following article to understand why: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx.

Comment: I was wrong.For plain rendering of html I have used @foreach. Thanks +1

Comment: Is there any work around for collections of type IEnumerable, other than index based access?

Comment: I try'ed changing my model type to IList. But it cause's my program to crash

Comment: @Panther, *it made my program to crash* is a pretty lousy problem description. You could have been a little more explicit. Maybe you got an error message or something that you could have shared with us. Anyway, make sure that you are passing an `IList<T>` instance to this view inside the controller action. You could use the `.ToList()` extension method on your model: `return View(model.ToList());`.

Comment: @amesh, links about what? Editor templates? I will post an answer here to illustrate.

Comment: I have all List, And set my model type to Ilist. It's now updating the Wanted_Stock fine But dropping the rest of the data in my tables.

Comment: @Panther It normal, because you send only edit input data to server, as solution for `DisplayFor` you can add `HiddenFor` for this properties.

Comment: Thank you for your time, You have all been a grate help and my problem is solved.

Comment: @Panther You can use this: `@Html.TextBoxFor(x = x.Prop, new { disabled = "disabled" })`

Answer (score 3):

You could use editor templates. I would recommend you to first read the [following article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) in order to understand why your code doesn't correctly bind the collection. Once you understand that you could do the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<FlatSystem.Models.Stock>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="sidemenu">
        <div class="sidemenu-heading">
            ReStock
        </div>
        <div class="div-body">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Wanted Stock</th>
                        <th>Stock On Hand</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @Html.EditorForModel()
                </tbody>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and now define a custom editor template for the `Stock` type which will automatically be rendered for each element of the collection (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Stock.cshtml`) - the name and location of the editor template is important as it works by convention:

```
@model FlatSystem.Models.Stock
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Item_Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Wanted_Stock)
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Actual_Stock)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Actual_Stock)
    </div>
    </td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
</tr>
```

Remark: You might also want to include the `Wanted_Stock` and `Item_Name` as hidden fields along with the `ID` in the editor template in order for their values to be sent to the server, because you don't have a corresponding input field for them.

Comment: It's Great one.. Do we need to manually load the editor template here? or @Html.EditorForModel() will do it by itself?

Comment: It will do it automatically, you don't need to load anything. It will look for an editor template inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` called `Stock.cshtml` because the main model is of type `IEnumerable<Stock>`.

Comment: @amesh one of the greatest advantages of this technique is automatically generation with one line, separate storing and reusability.