# How to preserve input ids when editing lists in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4, but I on't think that matters for the purpose of this question.

I have a relatively complex model for my edit view. Like this:

```
public class Recipe_model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Recipe_Ingredient_model> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

where Ingredients is

```
public class Recipe_Ingredient_model
{
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }

    public int? UnitID { get; set; }

    public double? Quantity { get; set; }

    public Ingredient_model Ingredient { get; set; }
}
```

which itself contains the Ingredient model.

When I make a form for this, the built-in `Html.EditorFor()` doesn't work for anything past the properties of the `Recipe_model`, so I'm using partial views to display the editor for each of the sub-models.

That works fine as far the interface goes, but when I submit the form to the controller and try to bind to the `Recipe_model` automatically using

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Recipe_model model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

it fails because the ids of the input elements in the partial views do not conform to the correct pattern (I think ParentModel_Property).

Short from hard-coding the ids in the partial view or binding manually from the `FormCollection` in the controller, is there some way to get the correct ids generated in the partial view so that the model will bind automatically on submit?

Comment: Can you post the code of your partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common problem. Instead of simple partials, use `EditorTemplates` (special folder for models) and binding will work automatically.

For example look at this question: [Updating multiple items within same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837288/updating-multiple-items-within-same-view/12837674#12837674)

Comment: Finally got to try this out. I can't get it to work... When I do a foreach (var listItem in Model.Items){ @Html.EditorFor(...);} I have no idea what to put in the Html.EditorFor() brackets to get this to work? I have tried @html.EditorFor(m => listItem, "ListItemEditorTemplate"), but that doesn't preserve the ids, so binding doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok, just tried with a for () loop instead of foreach and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the answer given by @WebDeveloper
you can also try and create a custom model binder though a little more complex but will add to the ease of posting and binding form value to the objects in long run
have a look here http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-model-binding

you will have to manually take all the form values and bind them to the `model` once and then you will be able to use the `@HtmlFrom` methods on the razor to do anything and you will get all the value inside the objects inside the `action methods` as you like.