# How to get table data from view is asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My question is how to get table data back to the controller from view?

I have class in my model:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

and I pass list of Companies to my view as:

```
    @model IEnumerable<MyTestApp.Web.Models.Company>
    ....
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Shop"))
    {
    <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Town)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Town)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }   
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

And everything looks ok, but I can't understand how to get modified data in the controller? I used these approaches:

```
public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<Company> companies)
    {
        // but companies is null
        // and ViewData.Model also is null

        return RedirectToAction("SampleList");
    }
```

I need access to modified objects, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to **webdeveloper**, I just needed use 'for' loop instead of 'foreach' loop. Right version is

```
<tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++ ) {
            <tr>                   
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Address)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Town)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }   
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, look at my answer here: [Updating multiple items within same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837288/updating-multiple-items-within-same-view) OR for **Darin Dimitrov** answer.

You need items with `index` in `name` attribute in rendered html markup. Also you could look at: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are missing the `Company`'s ID in your form so that the model can be correctly bound.

You should add it like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Shop"))
{
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            ...
```

Otherwise the rest of your code seems to be OK.

Comment: Thanks, Yannick, but I tried this right now and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your table rows by providing an id for each one being edited so mvc can bind to it back to the controller. One row of table data example:

```
@for (var a = 0; a < @Model.Pets.Count; a++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => @Model.Pets[a].ChildSelected, new { @id= a + "childSelected" })
        </td>
    </tr>
```