# Getting List<ViewModel> from View into Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `View` which allows editing a `List` of `ViewModel`. The code works till the displaying functionality. But I am unable to get the value in the same list back from the view.

```
        public ActionResult Funtion()
        {
            List<ViewModel> ViewModel= (List<ViewModel>)TempData["ViewModel"];
            return View(ViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserFormSubmission(List<ViewModel> ViewModel)
        {    
            return View();
        }
```

The value in List of the POST function is null.
How could i get the values from view into Controller.

**EDIT :**
I tried using the solutions mentioned to assolution to the question [How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state). But encountered the following error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Also i couldnt understand the usage of certain tags in it, like the `AntiForgeryToken`, `HiddenFor`, etc. 
So if possible someone please come up with a Simple solution or a better explanation.

**EDIT 2 :** I changed `@model IEnumerable<ViewModel>` to `@model List<ViewModel>` and the error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable has been corrected.

**EDIT 3:**
I was able to get the value of `Textbox` and `CheckBox` into the Controller but `RadioButton` and `DropDownList's selected values cant be identified at the`[HttpPost]` function? What am I missing here?

```
@for (i = 0; i < Model.Count(); ++i)
{
 if (Model[i].TypeId == 4)
                    {
                        //radiobutton
                        for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Options.Count(); ++j)
                        {
                    <div>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Options[j].OptionId)                        
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Options[j].OptionValue)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Options[j].Id)

                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Options[j].Value, @Model[i].Options[j].DisplayText)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Options[j].DisplayText)
                    </div>

                        }
                    }
}
```

Comment: Please,  add more codes about view, for example where is <form> html tag?

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu - That's irrelevant on the current situation. I have included only what is needed.

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question. Don't keep updating your existing one with independent problems as you'll end up with answers to different questions in the same list. You've solved your problem - your model is binding. Your problem with your RadioButtons and DropDownLists is separate.

Comment: @AntP - This is the same question. Thats why Its updated.

Comment: @Rohit No, it's a different question. Your original question was a problem with view model binding, which now works. Problem solved. Your next question is that some specific properties aren't binding. That's a different question. Meaning all of a sudden all of the existing - correct - answers no longer solve the problem and this Q&A is now a mess that is of now use to anyone. Instead of creating one massive monster question with 20 sub questions, create a new question with just the relevant information.

Comment: Its still all about viewmodel binding. And as you could see there is no specific answer. Its all References or how to go about it type. So I don't find a need for a new question yet. Maybe a better answer would come up that solves all the scenarios.

Comment: A better question would elicit better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to:

1. Use strongly typed view
2. Use `for(i = 0; ...; ...)` loops, else it will not work this simply

Another approach could be (**please don't use this approach**):

1. Create JSON array of the list on JS post event
2. Send an AJAX POST request to the controller with this data

Comment: I have updated my question. See if your answer is a solution in this scenario

Comment: @Rohit, I am not the right person to judge if my answer is correct or not. Select that answer as the solution that is logically correct (so that other fellow readers are not mis-lead) and the answer that gave you the solution or guided you to reach the solution :)

Comment: @Rohit, where is the `for(i = 0;...;...)` loop?

Comment: i replaced the `foreach` loop with `for(i=0;;)`

Comment: I thought so. Try with something like `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {`. See if `Model.Count()` or `Model.Length` should work. And inside the loop, use whatever variable/model you have, e.g. `data[i]`

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12837674/1654121 or http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Hidden Fields was the Key. Worked for textbox. But radiobutton, dropdownlist, and checkbox pending

Comment: Good. Now similarly you can make it work for other controls too :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the indexer istead of foreach statment to allow mvc to build your list back.
The simmilar question has already been asked [How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state)

Comment: I haad seen it and I tried using it. But ran into the following error : `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ViewModell>`

Comment: You need to change the type in the view, to use List instead of Ienumerable

Comment: The model declaration in views should be: @model List<ViewModel>

Comment: Yes have corrected it. See the edit. But still I get null values.

Comment: Can you post the current view with <form> tag?

Answer (score 1):

as the #theghostofc suggested you can use index based loop and controls using for to generate controls 
e.g.

```
for(int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
{
<tr>
<td>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>Model[i].Text)
</td>
<tr>    
}
```

And on form submission as you used the list of Models you can obtain it easily.

Comment: The problem is i Have more thane one type like TextBox, CheckBox,RadioButton,DropDownList,etc

Comment: you mean u have more than one type of control for same Property.? But if you mean you have other controls like checkbox or radiobutton or dropdownlist for different properties, then you have no problem on obtainning the selected values of these controls as well by using control with for tags as i have exaplined for textbox, but suitable datatype like Not Nullable boolean is required for checkbox and so on..